# jQuery Accordion suddenly stopped working

Tags: jquery

I used this code few days ago and the accordion was still working:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {
    /**
     * Jquery Accordion
     */
    $j('#list1b').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#list1c').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#list1d').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#list1e').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    /**
     * Nivo Slider
     */
    $j('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({max: 310, duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
    /**
     * Jplayer
     */
    var Playlist = function(instance, playlist, options) {
        var self = this;

        this.instance = instance; // String: To associate specific HTML with this playlist
        this.playlist = playlist; // Array of Objects: The playlist
        this.options = options; // Object: The jPlayer constructor options for this playlist

        this.current = 0;

        this.cssId = {
            jPlayer: "jquery_jplayer_",
            interface: "jp_interface_",
            playlist: "jp_playlist_"
        };
        this.cssSelector = {};

        $j.each(this.cssId, function(entity, id) {
            self.cssSelector[entity] = "#" + id + self.instance;
        });

        if(!this.options.cssSelectorAncestor) {
            this.options.cssSelectorAncestor = this.cssSelector.interface;
        }

        $j(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer(this.options);

        $j(this.cssSelector.interface + " .jp-previous").click(function() {
            self.playlistPrev();
            $j(this).blur();
            return false;
        });

        $j(this.cssSelector.interface + " .jp-next").click(function() {
            self.playlistNext();
            $j(this).blur();
            return false;
        });
    };

    Playlist.prototype = {
        displayPlaylist: function() {
            var self = this;
            $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + " ul").empty();
            for (i=0; i < this.playlist.length; i++) {
                var listItem = (i === this.playlist.length-1) ? "<li class='jp-playlist-last'>" : "<li>";
                listItem += "<a href='#' id='" + this.cssId.playlist + this.instance + "_item_" + i +"' tabindex='1'>"+ this.playlist[i].name +"</a>";

                // Create links to free media
                if(this.playlist[i].free) {
                    var first = true;
                    listItem += "<div class='jp-free-media'>(";
                    $j.each(this.playlist[i], function(property,value) {
                        if($j.jPlayer.prototype.format[property]) { // Check property is a media format.
                            if(first) {
                                first = false;
                            } else {
                                listItem += " | ";
                            }
                            listItem += "<a id='" + self.cssId.playlist + self.instance + "_item_" + i + "_" + property + "' href='" + value + "' tabindex='1'>" + property + "</a>";
                        }
                    });
                    listItem += ")</span>";
                }

                listItem += "</li>";

                // Associate playlist items with their media
                $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + " ul").append(listItem);
                $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + i).data("index", i).click(function() {
                    var index = $j(this).data("index");
                    if(self.current !== index) {
                        self.playlistChange(index);
                    } else {
                        $j(self.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("play");
                    }
                    $j(this).blur();
                    return false;
                });

                // Disable free media links to force access via right click
                if(this.playlist[i].free) {
                    $j.each(this.playlist[i], function(property,value) {
                        if($j.jPlayer.prototype.format[property]) { // Check property is a media format.
                            $j(self.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + i + "_" + property).data("index", i).click(function() {
                                var index = $j(this).data("index");
                                $j(self.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + index).click();
                                $j(this).blur();
                                return false;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        playlistInit: function(autoplay) {
            if(autoplay) {
                this.playlistChange(this.current);
            } else {
                this.playlistConfig(this.current);
            }
        },
        playlistConfig: function(index) {
            $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + this.current).removeClass("jp-playlist-current").parent().removeClass("jp-playlist-current");
            $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + index).addClass("jp-playlist-current").parent().addClass("jp-playlist-current");
            this.current = index;
            $j(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("setMedia", this.playlist[this.current]);
        },
        playlistChange: function(index) {
            this.playlistConfig(index);
            $j(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("play");
        },
        playlistNext: function() {
            var index = (this.current + 1 < this.playlist.length) ? this.current + 1 : 0;
            this.playlistChange(index);
        },
        playlistPrev: function() {
            var index = (this.current - 1 >= 0) ? this.current - 1 : this.playlist.length - 1;
            this.playlistChange(index);
        }
    };

    var videoPlaylist = new Playlist("1", [
        {
            name:"Big Buck Bunny Trailer",
            free:true,
            m4v:"http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v",
            ogv:"http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv",
            poster:"http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"
        },
        {
            name:"Finding Nemo Teaser",
            m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352_h264aac.m4v",
            ogv: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352.ogv",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352.png"
        },
        {
            name:"Incredibles Teaser",
            m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272_h264aac.m4v",
            ogv: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272.ogv",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272.png"
        }
    ], {
        ready: function() {
            videoPlaylist.displayPlaylist();
            videoPlaylist.playlistInit(false); // Parameter is a boolean for autoplay.
        },
        ended: function() {
            videoPlaylist.playlistNext();
        },
        play: function() {
            $j(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "ogv, m4v"
    });

    var audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2", [
        {
            name:"Tempered Song",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Lentement",
            free:true,
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-03-Lentement.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-03-Lentement.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Lismore",
            free:true,
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-04-Lismore.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04-Lismore.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"The Separation",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-05-The-separation.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-05-The-separation.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Beside Me",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-06-Beside-me.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-06-Beside-me.ogg"
        }

    ], {
        ready: function() {
            audioPlaylist.displayPlaylist();
            audioPlaylist.playlistInit(false); // Parameter is a boolean for autoplay.
        },
        ended: function() {
            audioPlaylist.playlistNext();
        },
        play: function() {
            $j(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "oga, mp3"
    });
});
```

Today, I realized that the accordion stopped working.

I tried the old code, but still not working (the pictures don't move):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {
    /**
     * Jquery Accordion
     */
    $j('#cd1').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd2').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd3').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd4').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd5').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd6').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd7').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd8').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd9').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#cd10').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    /**
     * Nivo Slider
     */
    $j('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({max: 310, duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
});
```

This is the accordion part:

```
$j('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({max: 310, duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
```

This is the live, website:

http://alexchen.info/brianfunshine/

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check your website with firebug -> Net, couldn't find few javascript files (custom.js and custom2.js)...

Comment: OK, I saw it in my firebug, I will check them out.